# Editor for laravel that can add url to a picture

Tags: laravel, editor

Sorry for a simple question here maybe. But I have a site that is built in laravel and for the blog, I can't add a picture and place a link to it so it will act as a CTA button. I am not a programmer and I have outsourced it to a company.

Now I just have a freelancer doing some small jobs and he tells me he needs 9-10 hours to fix this. That seems a lot to me and I wonder if anyone can share with me an editor that can do this and if you think his timing is out of wack.

Thank you

Nicklas

Comment: Hello ,  it looks like you are new to posting on this community.  Be sure to follow the stack overflow guidelines and ask specific questions about a coding project.  You're not likely going to just find some 'editor' that can do this for you. Unless you're going to get really into the specifics of what you are trying to do with examples then this is the wrong place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

this is for picture with button

```
<button type="submit" id="my_id" name="my_id"><img src=""></button>
```

this is for link with picture.. too

```
<a href="{{ route}}"><img src=""></a>
```

i think so this is helpfull for you...